# How to count the number of a given VALUE(!) in a C++ map?

Tags: c++, ios, algorithm, dictionary, range-based-loop

I do have a cpp class in an otherwise iOS/ObjC project. It uses the following map:

```
std::map <std::string, int> testMap;
```

I do know that I can "count" the number of appearances of a given key in that map via testMap.count. But how do I count the number of appearances of a given value in that map?

e.g. suppose to have the following  map:

```
<Anna, 5>
<Brian, 4>
<Cesar, 4>
<Danny, 3>
```

--> So if I look for the number of value "4" the function should return 2, for values "5" and "3" respectively it should return 1 for each, otherwise 0...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why has this been voted for closing (as being *off topic*)? I think this is a perfectly valid question fully within the scope of SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use `std::count_if` with an appropriate lambda:

```
int value = 4; // or something else

std::count_if(std::begin(testMap),
              std::end  (testMap),
              [value](std::pair<std::string, int> const &p) {
                return p.second == value;
              });
```

This simply walks through the map and counts all elements that fit the predicate.

Comment: You still need to catch the variable `value`.

Comment: @Wintermute: Thank you very much for your answer! I do not understand too much about c++... When replacing "value" with the name of my variable I get the following error: "Variable xyz cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified". A short google search indicated to change "[]" to "[=]" - but I do not fully understand it yet. Do you think this "change" is correct? (I will mark your answer as correct as soon as i can test it.)

Comment: If you want to use a variable, you have to capture it, as Walter rightly mentioned. In the case of `int value`, I'd use `[value]` instead of `[]` to capture `value` by value. Let me just edit that in. `[=]` would capture everything by value, which would also work but is a bit overkillish, and `[&]` or `[&value]` would also work but capture by reference. It does not make a real difference in this particular case.

Comment: @Wintermute: Xcode then complains: "expected ',' or ']' in lambda capture list" with the error indicator between the "=" and "value" in "[=value]", if I remove "value" it is "silent" but I do not know if that is right...

Answer (score 4):

It can be simply done using the range based for statement:)

```
size_t count = 0;
int value = 4;

for ( auto &p : testMap ) count += p.second == value;
```

Sometimes using the range based for statement looks more readable than using standard algorithm std::count_if.:)

On the other hand if this operation is used several times then it will be better to use the algorithm. For example

```
int value = 4;

size_t n = std::count_if( std::begin( testMap ), std::end( testMap ),
                          [&value]( const std::pair<const std::string, int> &p )
                          {
                              return p.second == value;
                          } );
```

Also you could define the lambda separately from calls of the algorithm

```
int value;
size_t n;

auto IsEqual = [&value]( const std::pair<const std::string, int> &p )
{
    return p.second == value;
};

value = 4;
n = std::count_if( std::begin( testMap ), std::end( testMap ), IsEqual );

//...

value = 5;
n = std::count_if( std::begin( testMap ), std::end( testMap ), IsEqual );
```

Comment: Since you answer is correct and I usually prefer to use ranged-based loops... Why not passing `value` by value to the lambda function rather than by reference?

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow: Thank you very much for your answer too, I will test it too!

Comment: @M M. If value is captured by reference then it will be enough to change the value that several times to call the algorithm for different values.